# What is the meaning of fork()&&fork()||fork() in c

Tags: c, fork

I have a doubt about fork process. I have a code which is

```
int main(int c, char **v){
  fork();
  fork() && fork() || fork();
  printf("Hello\t");
}
```

According to me the output of the above code will be
2<sup>4</sup>  = 16 times `"Hello"`, because each fork creates two copy of its own so the overall becomes `2*2*2*2` which are `16` times `"Hello"`.
But it's not correct it is giving me output as `10` times Hello. What is happening here?

Comment: What do the [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) function return in the parent process? What does it return in the child process? And how do [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) work? When you can answer that you know what will happen. Knowing [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) would also be helpful.

Comment: And some nitpicking: The `fork` function only creates two copies if you count the original parent process as a "copy".

Comment: It means either homework, a quiz, a '-F' mark or a pink slip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a brain teaser that tests your understanding of `fork` and how logical operators work in C. In particular their short circuit evaluation. It works based on these principles:

- `||` will not evaluate the second expression if the first evaluates to a truthy value (not 0).
- `&&` will not evaluate the second expression if the first evaluates to a falsy value (0).
- `&&` has greater precedence than `||`. So the "tricky" expression is equivalent to the fully parenthesized `((fork() && fork()) || fork());`
- `fork` returns 0 to the child process, and something other than 0 to the parent process. It returns -1 on failure, but evidently success is assumed in the problem.

With that in mind, we can trace process creation as follows:

1. The original process calls `fork` unconditionally. Thus resulting in 2 processes.
2. Each process from #1 calls the first `fork` in the logical expression. Each child thus created has a 0 returned, so it doesn't call the `fork` after the `&&`. The total number of processes is now 4.
3. The two processes from #1 *do* call the `fork` after the `&&`. They create another 2 processes. Bringing us up to a total of 6. The parents satisfy the left sub-expression of the `||` so they won't call `fork` anymore. The newly created children processes do not satisfy the `||` yet. So they will call the last `fork`.
4. The two children created in #2 and the two created in #3 call the last `fork` after the `||`. They spawn 4 more processes in total. Bringing the count up to 10.